# Ionic 3 issue while generating AAB file

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to create AAB file to upload into play store using Ionic 3 using below 2 commands. This was working fine before, but now it is showing attached issue. Don’t know what has been changed recently.

> ionic cordova build android --prod --release

> gradlew.bat bundleRelease

Issue i am facing

[image: Issue i am facing]

System Environment

[image: System Environment]

Appreciate your help, Thanks in advance